# finding p tag between two div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find out

tag between two different divs using jQuery. For example

```
<div class="abc">
    <div class="pqr">
        <h2>Header Two</h2>
            <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p>some text 1</p>
<div class="lmn">
      <p> some text </p>
</div>
```

So I want to find the p with  "some text 1". (the text could be anything.)

Can anyone tell me how can I do this ?

Comment: What specific criteria is the selector supposed to match? Any `<p>` element between two `<div>` tags? Any `<p>` element between any two different tags?

Comment: Is it possible for you to just take the element before `.lmn` and use that? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mLru9sec/1/. Or use an ID to identify the tag in between? That would be easier to read and more accurate.

Comment: I would recommend to change the current code and change _some text_ to something like _wrong text_ and _some text 1_ to something like _required text_ for better understanding of the question, even though the answer is already provided bellow

Comment: Hey Devid, It is any <p> element between two <div> tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

Basically, using the `+` tag, figure out if such a pattern exists, and then retrieve the required content

```
if($('.abc + p + .lmn').length) { // + matches the elements at the same level
    var x = $('.abc + p').text(); //Now that such a pattern exists , note that it could be multiple, so handle it appropriately, fetch the text
    console.log(x);
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrxqg0v2/1/)

Comment: Wouldn't `$('div div p').text()` match the OP query of _a tag between two different divs_ better ? I think _in between two different divs_ actually meant **nested** in two divs

Comment: No, I dont think so.. OP wants to match the same level node i.e `<p>some text 1</p>` - the space indicates nested elements, and not the same level element

Comment: oh yes sorry the "some text" and "some text 1" confused me.

Comment: If any `p` tag is between `.abc` and `.lmn` on the page, then this will match every `p` tag that follows `.abc` on the entire page, even if it has no `.lmn` following.

Comment: @user52889 That is the reaseon we have the outer `if` condition.

Comment: The if doesn't do what you think it is doing. It doesn't and can't be made to prevent the second line from matching cases which the if didn't.

Comment: @user52889 Well, this is just an idea. There are many edge cases uncovered in the solution.

Comment: @user52889 actually, thinking about your argument, it still doesnt make sense to me. Given the usecase, this works just fine. Either you are overthinking, or you dont understand the problem.

Comment: Given a structure `div>(div.abc+p+div.lmn)+div>(div.abc+p)`, the OP wants only the first `p` but your answer will return the second as well.

Comment: Nevermind.. I got what you are saying.. I would leave the answer the way it is.. There are ways to handle this by using better class names, etc..  I would leave that to the OP to figure out. But you are right.. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following will find all `p` tags which have preceding siblings `.abc` and following siblings `.lmn`:

```
$('.abc + p + .lmn').prevUntil('.abc','p')
```

If you just want ANY `p` tag between two `div`s, then do

```
$('div + p + div').prevUntil('div','p')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all p tags in your document and then check if the parent is div tag or not and then get the text of p tag of non parent div as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
       $("p").each(function(index){
         if (!$(this).parent().is("div")) alert($(this).text())         
       })     
    })
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://jsbin.com/sugodawiza/1/